# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I hoping someone can help with this.

I have created a class with a function in it that counts the total cars in 4 lists of cars.

On another script I am creating the interface and want to say if the answer to 'totalCars' is bigger than zero then proceed to offer a type of car.

However when I do this I get this error: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'`. Here is the code:

```
def totalCars(self):
    p = len(self.getPetrolCars())
    e = len(self.getElectricCars())
    d = len(self.getDieselCars())
    h = len(self.getHybridCars())
    totalCars = int(p) + int(e) + int(d) + int(h)
    return totalCars
```

And on the interface script have:

```
while self.totalCars > 0:
```

To get around this I tried to use a boolean, like this:

```
def totalCars(self):
    p = len(self.getPetrolCars())
    e = len(self.getElectricCars())
    d = len(self.getDieselCars())
    h = len(self.getHybridCars())
    totalCars = int(p) + int(e) + int(d) + int(h)
    if totalCars > 0:
        return True
```

And on the app script I have:

```
 while self.totalCars is True
```

But this totally crashed the program and won't run at all.

Any guidance welcome here. 
Many thanks.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @SimonH I edited the post because the indentation was there, only empty lines were missing from before the code blocks which broke formatting. Annelli: please use the preview feature when you ask/edit your question so that you can make sure that it looks the way it's supposed to.

Comment: It's `self.totalCars()` with parentheses. You didn't call the method.

Comment: len() returns an integer, no need for int cast.

Comment: Thanks Andras, I went back in to edit and saw someone already had. First time posting. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Thierry, that seems to have gotten passed that issue.... Only to raise another issue though grr!!! cheers for the help :)

Answer (score 10):

That's because `self.totalCars` is a method and you need to *call* it to get it's return value by adding a couple parenthesis at the end, like so:

```
while self.totalCars() > 0:
     #Insert the rest here
```

Otherwise, like the message says, you're comparing a method with a number, and that's not gonna work.

No need to add a boolean, but if you insisted on using one, you could do something like:

```
while self.totalCars():    #Will run if self.totalCars() RETURNS True
```

Again, this didn't really work in your original code because you forgot the parenthesis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Crap, I meant the "original" `totalCars()`. I should clear that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same when you are using `count`,

I had this issue when I were using `count`

```
Model1.objects.filter(user=self.user).count > 1
```

Adding parentheses after `count` will make it work

```
Model1.objects.filter(user=self.user).count() > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your last question, you just need this:

```
while self.totalCars():
```

Call the method, but don't check against `True`if it returns a Boolean.

Also

```
def totalCars(self):
```

should end with:

```
return False
```

You should also point the exact location of the error next time.

Answer (score 0):

Without calling method, no data is return so it can't be compared to a number.

you just add `"()"`

```
while self.totalCars > 0:
=> while self.totalCars() > 0:
```